# React's output not responding

Tags: reactjs

Hello I'm new to ReactJs. I tried to run this code in my browser but the output was blank. Please help.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>react</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.13.3/JSXTransformer.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.29/browser.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/bable">
    var HelloWorld = React.CreateClass({
        render: function() {
            return <div>
                <h1> Hello World! </h1>
                <p>This is some text</p>
            </div>
        }
    });
    React.render(<HelloWorld />, document.body);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/bable">
    var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <h1> Hello World! </h1>
                    <p>This is some text</p>
                </div>
            )
        }
    });

    ReactDOM.render(<HelloWorld />, document.body);

</script>
```

First, use `React.createClass`
Second, enclose your return in () since you are returning a block of DOM elements
Third, we use `ReactDOM.render()` now instead of React.render()